# Find all roots of $p(z)=z^6+z^3-6$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Find all the roots of the complex polynomial $p(z)=z^6+z^3-6$

I cant find any roots however and Im not sure how to simplify if I have a root to start with.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but this is a quadratic in $z^3$.

Comment: It will only have three complex conjugate pairs if there are no real roots. But $p(0)=-6,$ $p(2)>0, p(-2)>0.$

Comment: Or, write it as $\left(z^6-4\right)+\left(z^3-2\right)=\dots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can factorise $P(z)=0$ as $(z^3-2)(z^3+3)=0$ then you need to find all three roots of $z^3=2$ and $z^3=-3$. Then you can write the rest of the roots just in cube root form like $z=(-3)^{\frac13}$ or $(-1)^{\frac23}2^{\frac13}$.